# Rails 3: add object using collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I have the following code inside the _forms view.

```
<div class="field">
   Shop: <%= f.collection_select :shop, @shop, :shopname, :shopname %><br />
</div>
```

However, no object is added to the database when I submit the form. This however works:

```
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :shop %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :shop %>
  </div>
```

This where I am adding manually the id. The collection_select does retrieve all the shopnames in the dropdown list.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like that is better if shop is really a reference in your case

```
<div class="field">
   Shop: <%= f.collection_select :shop_id, @shops, :id, :shopname %><br />
</div>
```